# How to enable Objects inclusion inside the HTMLEditor of Moodle?

Tags: html, tinymce, wysiwyg, moodle, html-editor

How can I add a Flash/Object button in the HTMLEditor of Moodle ?

I am looking for the same kind of button as the link button, with a browse proposition that allows me to link a swf file in the Editor.

I there a plugin for that already ? Do I have to develop it ?

I saw that it is possible with TinyMCE. Is it possible to deploy TinyMCE on moodle ?

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: I found this : http://moodle.capilanou.ca/mod/book/view.php?id=2451&chapterid=9#link%20editor but it doesn't work out of the box for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to install http://docs.moodle.org/en/Multimedia_plugins

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE should be usable(deployable) with Moodle.